# Power shell: after output, scroll to the very top

Tags: powershell

I have the script below, that is meant to be tailing something I'm outputting with a python script. The issue is that memorizer_output.txt can get very long, and I'd like the powershell to scroll to the very top on each loop. How could I do this?

```
while($true)
{
    clear
    Get-Content memorizer_output.txt
    Start-Sleep 5
}
```

Comment: `Get-Content memorizer_output.txt | more`?

Comment: @DavidPostill very neat, I didn't know about `| more`, thank you!

Comment: @shintuku, know that ```more``` is not cmdlet/alias for one, and you can see that just by asking PowerShell. For example: ```Get-command -Name more``` or ```Get-help -Name more``` or ```(Get-Command -CommandType Application) -match 'more*'``` or ```Get-Command -ShowCommandInfo more```. Also, ```more``` is a legacy tool, that has been around since before PS ever existed, yet, PS allows you to see ```*.exe``` in your PS code inline, as long as you pass it all it requires; as seen here: [TechNet](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7703.powershell-running-executables.aspx)